# How would I correctly align the following?

Tags: alignment

Any ideas on how I'd be able to align as illustrated below without the use of tables?

[image: Alignment]

Comment: Please post what you have done as a MWE and explain what you find unsatisfactory in your image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a friendlier input syntax (at the expense of the code):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{derivation}{b}
 {
  \bool_gset_false:N \g_vanderwalt_derivation_therefore_bool
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_vanderwalt_derivation_body_seq { \\ } { #1 }
  \begin{alignedat}{2}
  \seq_map_function:NN \l_vanderwalt_derivation_body_seq \vanderwalt_derivation_line:n
  \end{alignedat}
 }{}

\bool_new:N \g_vanderwalt_derivation_therefore_bool
\seq_new:N \l_vanderwalt_derivation_body_seq
\seq_new:N \l_vanderwalt_derivation_line_seq
\tl_new:N \l_vanderwalt_derivation_line_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \vanderwalt_derivation_line:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_vanderwalt_derivation_line_seq { & } { #1 }
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_vanderwalt_derivation_line_tl { & }
  \bool_if:NTF \g_vanderwalt_derivation_therefore_bool
   { \tl_put_right:Nn \l_vanderwalt_derivation_line_tl { \therefore } }
   { \bool_gset_true:N \g_vanderwalt_derivation_therefore_bool }
  \tl_put_right:Nx \l_vanderwalt_derivation_line_tl
   {
    \seq_item:Nn \l_vanderwalt_derivation_line_seq { 1 }
    & \exp_not:N \qquad &
    \int_compare:nT { \seq_count:N \l_vanderwalt_derivation_line_seq > 1 }
     {
      \exp_not:N \text{(\seq_item:Nn \l_vanderwalt_derivation_line_seq { 2 })}
     }
    \exp_not:N \\
   }
  \tl_use:N \l_vanderwalt_derivation_line_tl
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{derivation}
4x^2 - 12x = -8 \\
x^2 - 3x = -2               & divide all terms by $4$ \\
x^2 - 3x + 2 = 0            & write in standard form \\
(x - 2)(x - 1) = 0          & factorise \\
x-2 = 0 \text{ or } x-1 = 0 & apply the zero factor law \\
x = 2 \text{ or } x = 1
\end{derivation}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The environment `derivation` gathers its content and splits it at `\\`. Then each line is processed and from `<formula> & <text>` the line is transformed into

```
& <formula> & \qquad & \text{(<text>)} \\
```

A `\therefore` symbol is added starting from the second line; the `<text>` in parentheses is added only if something is added after an `&`.

The code is executed in an `alignedat` environment.

It would be the same with

```latex
\begin{equation*}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
& 4x^2 - 12x = -8 \\
& \therefore x^2 - 3x = -2               &\qquad& \text{divide all terms by $4$} \\
& \therefore x^2 - 3x + 2 = 0            &\qquad& \text{write in standard form} \\
& \therefore (x - 2)(x - 1) = 0          &\qquad& \text{factorise} \\
& \therefore x-2 = 0 \text{ or } x-1 = 0 &\qquad& \text{apply the zero factor law} \\
& \therefore x = 2 \text{ or } x = 1
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation*}
```

but the input syntax is much heavier.

Comment: +1: That's a lot of code!

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Yes, but the gain is big when one has several of those derivations.

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain it with two alignments side by side:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
 & 4x^2-12x = -8\\
 & \therefore x^2-3x = -2 & & \text{ (divide all terms by 4)}\\
 & \therefore x^2-3x + 2 = 08 & & \text{ (write in standard form)}\\
 & \therefore (x-2)(x-1)=0 & & \text{ (factorise)}\\
 & \therefore x-2 = 0\text{ or } x-1= 0 & & \text{ (apply the zero factor law)}\\
 & \therefore x = 2 \text{ or }x =1
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is this a start?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
4x^2-12x = -8 & \text{ (Text Text Text)}\\
4x^2-12x = -88 & \text{ (Text Text Text)}\\
4x^2-12x = -8 & \text{ (Text Text Text)}\\
4x^2-12x = -888 & \text{ (Text Text Text)}\\
4x^2-12x = -8 & \text{ (Text Text Text)}\\
4x^2-12x = -88 & \text{ (Text Text Text)}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]